# Set autocapitalizationType globally for all uitextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, capitalization

I would like to set autocapitalizationType for all UITextFields in my application globally. Can I do this by overriding a method in a category for UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

No, categories extend the functionality of a class.
You could subclass UITextField, set the value you want, and use your subclass everywhere you want that behavior,